# flattening a list attribute using PartiSQL for DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I would like to ask how we can flatten a list filed in DynamoDB using PartiSQL. Thanks!

This is the data format

```
 "a": "aa",
 "list_value": [
  "a",
  "b",
  "c"
 ]
}
```

This is the partisql query

```
SELECT p
FROM "tablename"."indexname" ,  list_value AS p
WHERE ....
```

It gets `ValidationException: Only select from a single table or index is supported.` error

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get rows like so?

```
"a"  
"b"  
"c"
```

You can't.

Dynamo just supports a subset of the partiSQL syntax;  `JOIN` is not included.  Nor are any `TABLE` type functions that you're used to having in a RDBMS query engine.

```
SELECT list_value
FROM "tablename"."indexname"
WHERE ....
```

will give you back `"a","b","c"` you'll have to break it down from there in your client app.

Comment: Thanks Charles!

With this value
``` "a": "aa",
 "list_value": [
  "a",
  "b",
  "c"
 ]
}
```
I would like to get a list of value [aa_a, aa_b, aa_c] from first table, then use them to filter a second DynamoDB table.

select * from tableB where field in [[aa_a, aa_b, aa_c]].

Charles, do you have any suggestion how I can implement this?